# Drop variables with all missing values

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I have `5000` variables and `91,534` observations in my dataset.

I want to drop all variables that have all their values missing:

```
X1     X2    X3
1      2      .
.      3      .
3      .      .
.      5      .
```

```
X1     X2
1      2  
.      3   
3      . 
.      5
```

I tried using the `dropmiss` *community-contributed* command, but it does not seem to be working for me even after reading the help file. For example:

```
dropmiss 
command dropmiss is unrecognized
r(199);

missings dropvars
force option required with changed dataset
```

Instead, as suggested in one of the solutions, I tried the following:

```
ssc install nmissing
nmissing, min(91534)  
drop `r(varlist)'
```

This alternative *community-contributed* command seems to work for me.

However, I wanted to know if there is a more elegant solution, or a way to use `dropmiss`.

Comment: So, you didn't install `dropmiss` or you installed it in the wrong place. That would be an explanation. However, I don't know how you could read the help file if you hadn't installed it. Either way, `missings` is now considered better (by all the program authors concerned).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an up-to-date Stata either `search dropmiss` or `search nmissing` will tell you that both commands are superseded by `missings` from the *Stata Journal*.

The following dialogue may illuminate your question:

```
. sysuse auto , clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. generate empty = .
(74 missing values generated)

. missings dropvars
force option required with changed dataset
r(4);

. missings dropvars, force

Checking missings in make price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length turn
    displacement gear_ratio foreign empty:
74 observations with missing values

note: empty dropped
```

`missings dropvars`, once installed, will drop all variables that are entirely missing, except that you need the `force` option if the dataset in memory has not been `save`d.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply loop over all variables in your dataset and use the `capture` and `assert` commands to test which ones have all their values missing.

The advantage of this approach is that you can do this with only *built-in* Stata commands:

```
clear

input X1 X2 X3
1 2 .
. 3 .
3 . .
. 5 .
end

list
     +--------------+
     | X1   X2   X3 |
     |--------------|
  1. |  1    2    . |
  2. |  .    3    . |
  3. |  3    .    . |
  4. |  .    5    . |
     +--------------+

foreach var of varlist _all {
    capture assert missing(`var')
    if !_rc {
        drop `var'
    }
}

list
     +---------+
     | X1   X2 |
     |---------|
  1. |  1    2 |
  2. |  .    3 |
  3. |  3    . |
  4. |  .    5 |
     +---------+
```